# Haskell: Lists vs Streams

Tags: list, haskell, stream

I've noticed [streams](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/vector/0.9.1/doc/html/Data-Vector-Fusion-Stream.html) seem to act a lot like lists, except with constant time append. Of course, adding constant time append to lists isn't too complicated, and [DList](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/dlist/0.5/doc/html/Data-DList.html) does exactly that.

Lets assume for the rest of the discussion that either lists have constant time append, or that we're simply not interested in it.

My thought is that Haskell lists should simply be implemented as streams. For this not to be the case, I assume that the following would need to hold:

1. There are cases where lists are better than streams **AND**
2. There are cases where streams are better than lists.

My question is: what are examples of the two above cases?

*Note: For the purpose of this question, please ignore easily fixable omissions in the particular implementations I've discussed. I'm looking more for core structural differences here.*

**Additional info:**

I guess part of what I'm getting at here is say if we write `[1..1000000]`, does a Haskell compiler (say GHC) do:

1. Make a list **OR**
2. Make an object with two ints: 1 and 1000000 which fully describes the list.

If it's case (1), why do this, as creating intermediate lists seems to be an unnecessary performance penalty?

Or if it's case (2), then why do we need streams?

Comment: Hm, what makes you say streams have constant time append/prepend? From the implementation, it looks like appending n elements will result in a `step` function that must traverse O(n) seeds with `Either` constructors nested O(n) deep. The documentation doesn't make this constant-time claim anywhere that I can see, either.

Comment: @DanielWagner: Fair enough. In any case, that makes streams even more like lists.

Comment: Actually, that makes them very different. With lists, cons is free, and you pay for snoc and concatenate based on the length of the first list; in comparison, with streams you pay for the depth of the concatenation tree, and the sizes of the things being concatenated is irrelevant. But that difference isn't what makes streams important.

Comment: Oh, you think `cons` isn't constant time? That's awkward. I'll have a look.

Comment: Ah, I see where the confusion may have arisen. In my first comment above, when I wrote "appending n elements", I really meant "appending n elements _one at a time_".

Answer (score 21):

When you write `[1..1000000]`, what GHC really does is create an object that contains `1` and `1000000` that describes how to build the list of interest; that object is called a "thunk". The list is only built as necessary to satisfy case scrutinees; for example, you might write:

```
printList [] = putStrLn ""
printList (x:xs) = putStrLn (show x) >> printList xs

main = printList [1..1000000]
```

Which evaluates like this:

```
main
= { definition of main }
printList [1..1000000]
= { list syntax sugar }
printList (enumFromTo 1 1000000)
= { definition of printList }
case enumFromTo 1 1000000 of
    [] -> putStrLn ""
    x:xs -> putStrLn (show x) >> printList xs
= { we have a case, so must start evaluating enumFromTo;
    I'm going to skip a few steps here involving unfolding
    the definition of enumFromTo and doing some pattern
    matching }
case 1 : enumFromTo 2 1000000 of
    [] -> putStrLn ""
    x:xs -> putStrLn (show x) >> printList xs
= { now we know which pattern to choose }
putStrLn (show 1) >> printList (enumFromTo 2 1000000)
```

Then you'd find that `1` was printed to the console, and we'd start from near the top with `enumFromTo 2 1000000` instead of `enumFromTo 1 1000000`. Eventually, you'd get all the numbers printed and it would come time to evaluate

```
printList (enumFromTo 1000000 1000000)
= { definition of printList }
case enumFromTo 1000000 1000000 of
    [] -> putStrLn ""
    x:xs -> putStrLn (show x) >> printList xs
= { skipping steps again to evaluate enumFromTo }
case [] of
    [] -> putStrLn ""
    x:xs -> putStrLn (show x) >> printList xs
= { now we know which pattern to pick }
putStrLn ""
```

and evaluation would be finished.

The reason we need streams is a bit subtle. The original paper, [Stream fusion: From lists to streams to nothing at all](http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.104.7401), probably has the most complete explanation. The short version is that when you have a long pipeline:

```
concatMap foo . map bar . filter pred . break isSpecial
```

...it's not so obvious how to get the compiler to compile away all the intermediate lists. You might notice that we can think of the lists as having a sort of "state" that's being iterated, and that each of these functions, rather than traversing a list, is just changing the way the state gets modified on each iteration. The `Stream` type tries to make this explicit, and the result is stream fusion. Here's how it looks: we first convert all these functions into stream versions:

```
(toList . S.concatMap foo . fromList) .
(toList . S.map bar . fromList) .
(toList . S.filter pred . fromList) .
(toList . S.break isSpecial . fromList)
```

then observe that we can always annihilate `fromList . toList`:

```
toList . S.concatMap foo . S.map bar . S.filter pred . S.break . fromList
```

...and then the magic happens because the chain `S.concatMap foo . S.map bar . S.filter pred . S.break` builds up an iterator explicitly rather than building it implicitly by internally building and then immediately annihilating actual lists.

Comment: I've had a look at the `Data.Vector.Fusion.Stream` source, and I can't find `fromList` and `toList`. My feeling is that `Data.Vector.Fusion.Stream` avoids creating lists in the first place. Is that wrong?

Comment: @Clinton I'm not really sure what part of my post made you think I'm suggesting that stream fusion goes via lists. It's quite the opposite: list fusion goes via streams. Getting list fusion right is the whole reason streams exist, as I tried to explain in my answer.

Comment: The part of the comment where the you said: "The Stream type tries to make this explicit, and the result is stream fusion. Here's how it looks: we first convert all these functions into stream versions: (toList . S.concatMap foo . fromList)...". But when I look at the source of `Data.Vector.Fusion.Stream`, I can't find such a conversion.

Comment: A lot of confusion in this post comes from the fact that you said "stream" and many people though you meant the stream datatype from the stream package or from the list fusion paper. But in fact you're referencing the Stream datatype that's used to implement stream fusion in the vector package... It works somewhat similarly, except that the conversion are called `stream` and `unstream`. To see the conversion, look at the source code of Data.Vector.Generic for the function `indexed` (amongst many other : vector make extensive use of stream fusion for performance).

Comment: @Clinton Stream fusion in this case design the optimisation technique that vector uses to avoid creating a bunch of intermediate vectors which would be even costlier than in the list case. It is very close to the technique used in list fusion (and you have "stream fusion for lists" which fuses more operations than list fusion and that you can find in the stream-fusion package).

Comment: @Clinton That sentence is talking about how list fusion is implemented (on top of stream fusion), not how stream fusion is implemented.

Answer (score 9):

The advantage of streams is they are more powerful. The interface:

```
data Stream m a = forall s . Stream (s -> m (Step s a)) s Size
```

lets you do many things that normal lists cannot. Eg:

- Track the size (eg Unknown, Max 34, Exact 12)
- Perform monadic actions to get the next element. Lists can partly do this with lazy IO, but that technique has proved to be error prone, and normally is only used by beginners, or for simple small scripts.

However, they have a big downside as compared to lists - complexity! For a beginner programmer, to understand streams you have to be on top of existential types and monadic actions. It would be very hard to learn haskell if to use the basic list type you had to learn those two complex subjects.

Compare that to lists, which have the interface:

```
data [] a = a : [a] | []
```

This is very simple, and something that can be taught easily to a new programmer.

Another advantage of lists is you can pattern match them simply. For example:

```
getTwo (a : b : _) = Just (a,b)
getTwo _ = Nothing
```

This is both useful to experienced programmers (I still use list pattern matching in many methods), and for beginner programmers who haven't yet learnt the standard higher order functions that can be used to manipulate lists.

Efficiency is also another potential advantage of lists, since ghc has spent a lot of time working on list fusion. In a lot of code, intermediate lists are never generated. That could be a lot harder to optimize with streams.

So I think it would be a poor choice to swap lists with Streams. The current situation is better, where you can bring them in if you need them, but beginners aren't stuck with their complexity and skilled users don't have to lose pattern matching.

EDIT: about `[1..1000000]`:

This is equivalent to `enumFromTo 1 1000000`, which is lazily evaluated, and subject to fusion (which makes it very efficient). Eg `sum [1..1000000]` would not generate any lists (and use constant memory) with optimisation turned on. So case (2) is correct, this situation isn't an advantage for streams due to lazy evaluation. As noted above though, streams have other advantages over lists.

Comment: You say lists can be more efficient than streams due to list fusion. But with streams, the lists aren't generated in the first place! Surely no list is no worse than a fused list. And if there are lists inside streams, can't you still fuse them in the same way?

Comment: "Not generating the list" is what list fusion does.The code is effectively compiled down into a c like for loop. It can't do it in all cases like Danial Wagner noted, but it does work in many situations.

Comment: I agree. But how is a list "not generating a list" better than a stream "not generating a list". You seem to imply list fusion can make lists better than streams, not just equal to streams.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean now. Whether they are equally or more efficient depend on whether the optimisations noted in the paper have made it into the ghc main branch, and work for many different scenarios. There is no theoretical reason I can think of as to why lists would be faster than streams, just that lists have been around longer and likely have had more work done for optimisation. We would need a benchmark with many list like tests to resolve which is faster currently. I did note it as a potential advantage of lists, not an actual one :P

Answer (score 7):

Short answer: lists and streams are incomparable in power. Streams allow monadic actions but disallow sharing while lists are vice versa.

A longer answer:

1) See @nanothief for a counterexample which cannot be implemented with lists
2) Below is a counterexample which cannot be easily implemented with streams

The problem is that toy list examples usually don't use the sharing feature of lists. Here is the code:

```
foo = map heavyFunction bar
baz = take 5 foo
quux = product foo
```

With lists you compute the heavy function only once. The code to compute `baz` and `quux`  with streams without extra computations of `heavyFunction` is going to be hard to maintain.